# Большой текст в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите пожалуйста придумать логику приложения "Читалка книг".  То что пришло в голову: Я беру большой текст из 20тыс+ символов. Обрезаю этот текст на несколько частей и вставляю при каждом свайпе в RecyclerView.
Но проблема в том, что я указываю позицию в substring явно. Вот например указал 1300 и на экране содержится 1300 символов, но потом если я меняю размер шрифта, то пол экрана бывает пустой.

```
      private int start;
      private int end = 1300;
         

        for (int j = 0; j < wordsArr.length; j++) {
            wordsArr[j] = bookTables.get(0).getDetailOfTitle().substring(start, end);
            start = end;
            end += 1300;
         
        }
     PageReadAdapter adapter = new PageReadAdapter(this, wordsArr);

//RecyclerView
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BookPageReadHolder holder, int position) {
   
            holder.tvDetail.setText(bookTablesList[position]);
 
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: делай больше символов и вставь туда scroll

Comment: Совсем не то. Мне нужно, чтобы можно было перелистывать страницы, и на каждую страницу часть текста.

Comment: Предлагаю сделать что-нибудь такое: рассчитать размер экрана, найти размер одной строки, вычислить количество строк, умещающихся на экране. Разумеется, необходимо [учитывать и межстрочный интервал](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29139914).